# Garry's Mod HatsChat2 chat colors permissions messed up?

Tags: lua

So I'm making a garry's mod server and I'm trying to work on my chat box addon that I installed and was working on that only premium and superadmin can use colors in the chat and only want them to be able to do all the colors below in the code, so here's what I did and edited in my chatbox code:

```
HatsChat = HatsChat or {} --Autorefresh goes weird without the "HatsChat or"
HatsChat.GetPlayerRank = function(ply)
    return string.lower((exsto and ply.GetRank and ply:GetRank()) or --Exsto
        (ply.EV_GetRank and ply:EV_GetRank()) or --Evolve
        (ply.GetUserGroup and ply:GetUserGroup()) or --ULX
        "" --Failed
    )
end

--Editable Vars--
-----------------
--Every variable must keep the same format when you edit it--

--Restrictions
--------------
local DonatorRank = {
    --Chances are I've missed some, add your own donators ranks here. Remember it already runs through a ply:IsAdmin() check too
    ["premium"] = true, ["premium+"] = true, ["premium++"] = true, ["premiumhelper"] = true, ["premiummoderator"] = true,
    ["premiumadmin"] = true, ["premiumsnrmod"] = true, ["premiumdeveloper"] = true, ["none"] = true, ["none"] = true,
    ["none"] = true, ["none"] = true, ["none"] = true, ["none"] = true,
}
local function AdminOnly(ply) return IsValid(ply) and ply:IsAdmin() end --Just an example. Remember, this is client side!
local function DonatorOnly(ply) return IsValid(ply) and (ply:IsAdmin() or DonatorRank[HatsChat.GetPlayerRank(ply)]) end

--Line Icons
------------
HatsChat.LineIcon = {
    --Add your rank icon stuff here
    ["donator"] = "materials/icon16/coins.png", --An example

    --Add specific SteamIDs in this format for single-player icons
    ["STEAM_0:0:0"] = "materials/icon16/shield.png",
    --Example for multiple icons (Experimental)
    ["STEAM_0:0:0"] = {"materials/icon16/heart.png","materials/icon16/shield_add.png"},

    --Defaults
    --These are used if the rank check fails, or if there's no icon for the rank
    ["DefaultSuperAdmin"] = "materials/icon16/shield_add.png",
    ["DefaultAdmin"] = "materials/icon16/shield.png",
    ["DefaultUser"] = "", --Remove this line if you don't want standard users to have line icons

    Global = "", --This icon is used for global messages, not player lines
}

--Chat Colors
-------------
HatsChat.ChatCol = {
    ["[red]"] = Color(255,0,0,255),
    ["[green]"] = Color(0,255,0,255),
    ["[blue]"] = Color(0,0,255,255),
    ["[black]"] = Color(0,0,0,255),
    ["[white]"] = Color(255,255,255,255),

    ["[pink]"] = Color(255,0,255,255),
    ["[teal]"] = Color(0,255,255,255),
    ["[yellow]"] = Color(255,255,0),

    --Minecraft colours
    ["%0"] = Color(0,0,0),      ["§0"] = Color(0,0,0), --Random escape character, the string is actually �0
    ["%1"] = Color(0,0,170),    ["§1"] = Color(0,0,170),
    ["%2"] = Color(0,170,0),    ["§2"] = Color(0,170,0),
    ["%3"] = Color(0,170,170),  ["§3"] = Color(0,170,170),
    ["%4"] = Color(170,0,0),    ["§4"] = Color(170,0,0),
    ["%5"] = Color(170,0,170),  ["§5"] = Color(170,0,170),
    ["%6"] = Color(255,170,0),  ["§6"] = Color(255,170,0),
    ["%7"] = Color(170,170,170),["§7"] = Color(170,170,170),
    ["%8"] = Color(85,85,85),   ["§8"] = Color(85,85,85),
    ["%9"] = Color(85,85,255),  ["§9"] = Color(85,85,255),
    ["%a"] = Color(85,255,85),  ["§a"] = Color(85,255,85),
    ["%b"] = Color(85,255,255), ["§b"] = Color(85,255,255),
    ["%c"] = Color(255,85,85),  ["§c"] = Color(255,85,85),
    ["%d"] = Color(255,85,255), ["§d"] = Color(255,85,255),
    ["%e"] = Color(255,255,85), ["§e"] = Color(255,255,85),
    ["%f"] = Color(255,255,255),["§f"] = Color(255,255,255),

    ["[gray]"] = {r=150,g=150,b=150,a=255, restriction=SuperAdminOnly}, --Restrictions are written out completely differently from normal

    ["[rainbow]"] = {r=255,g=0,b=0,a=255, restriction=SuperAdminOnly, restriction=PremiumOnly}, --Just for fun
    ["[gold]"] = {r=255,g=210,b=50,a=255, restriction=SuperAdminOnly, restriction=PremiumOnly, Glow=true}, --Example for glows
}

--Emotes
--------
HatsChat.Emote = {
    {text=":tux:", icon="materials/icon16/tux.png"},
    {text=":usr:", icon="materials/icon16/user.png"},
    {text=":bomb:", icon="materials/icon16/bomb.png"},
    {text=":box:", icon="materials/icon16/box.png"},
    {text=":cake:", icon="materials/icon16/cake.png"},
    {text=":clock:", icon="materials/icon16/clock.png"},

    {text=":money:", icon="materials/icon16/money.png"},
    {text=":$:", icon="materials/icon16/money_dollar.png"}, --Other currency symbols don't seem to work
    {text=":S:", icon="materials/icon16/money_dollar.png"},
    {text=":E:", icon="materials/icon16/money_euro.png"},
    {text=":Y:", icon="materials/icon16/money_yen.png"},

    {text="<--", icon="materials/icon16/arrow_left.png"},
    {text="-->", icon="materials/icon16/arrow_right.png"},
    {text=":up:", icon="materials/icon16/arrow_up.png"},
    {text=":dn:", icon="materials/icon16/arrow_down.png"},

    {text=":coins:", icon="materials/icon16/user_suit.png", restricted=DonatorOnly},
    {text=":suit:", icon="materials/icon16/house.png", restricted=DonatorOnly},
    {text=":!:", icon="materials/icon16/error.png", restricted=DonatorOnly},
    {text=":date:", icon="materials/icon16/date.png", restricted=DonatorOnly},
    {text=":door:", icon="materials/icon16/door.png", restricted=DonatorOnly},
    {text=":home:", icon="materials/icon16/house.png", restricted=DonatorOnly},
    {text=":cup:", icon="materials/icon16/cup.png", restricted=DonatorOnly},

    {text="<3", icon="materials/icon16/heart.png", restricted=DonatorOnly},
    {text=":?:", icon="materials/icon16/help.png", restricted=DonatorOnly},

    {text=":)", icon="materials/icon16/emoticon_smile.png"},
    {text=">:D", icon="materials/icon16/emoticon_evilgrin.png"},
    {text=":D", icon="materials/icon16/emoticon_grin.png"},
    {text=":(", icon="materials/icon16/emoticon_unhappy.png"},
    {text=";)", icon="materials/icon16/emoticon_wink.png"},
    {text=":3", icon="materials/icon16/emoticon_waii.png"},
    {text=":o", icon="materials/icon16/emoticon_surprised.png"},
    {text=":P", icon="materials/icon16/emoticon_tongue.png"},

    {text=":shield:", icon="materials/icon16/shield.png", restricted=AdminOnly},
}

--Fonts
-------
--*NOTE* Automatic fastdl scripts might not add fonts!
HatsChat.FontData = { --Fonts for chatbox output
    --ManualShadow draws via lua, looks a lot sharper. Without it, most fonts are unusable
    --You can use standard shadows if you wish
    {name = "HatsChatText", font = "Arial", ManualShadow = true},
    {name = "HatsChatPrompt", font = "Arial", size = 15, ManualShadow = true}, --Used in the chatbox prompt
    {name = "Coolvetica", font = "Coolvetica", weight = 500, ManualShadow = true},

    {name = "Roboto", font = "Roboto Bk", weight = 500, ManualShadow = true},

    {name = "Reactor Sans", filename = "resource/fonts/Reactor-Sans.ttf", font = "Reactor Sans", ManualShadow = true}, --filename arg is for custom fonts
    {name = "Pricedown", filename = "resource/fonts/pricedown bl.ttf", font = "pricedown bl", ManualShadow = true},
    {name = "Steelfish", filename = "resource/fonts/steelfish rg.ttf", font = "steelfish rg", ManualShadow = true},
    {name = "Liberation Sans", filename = "resource/fonts/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf", font = "Liberation Sans", ManualShadow = true},
    {name = "Monofur", filename = "resource/fonts/monof55.ttf", font = "monofur", ManualShadow = true},
    {name = "Philosopher", filename = "resource/fonts/Philosopher-Regular.ttf", font = "Philosopher", ManualShadow = true},
}

-----------------------------------------
-------Chat stuff-------
-----------------------------------------
--Editting anything below here may cause instability in the addon

if CLIENT then --For Rainbows!
    local status, inv = 0
    hook.Add( "Think", "HatsChat ChatCol ModifyColours", function()
        local rbow = HatsChat.ChatCol["[rainbow]"]
        local mod = inv and 255-((math.sin( CurTime()*2 )+1) * 127.5) or ((math.sin( CurTime()*2 )+1) * 127.5)
        if status==0 then
            if mod>240 then status = 1 end

            rbow.r = mod --[[High]] rbow.g = 255-mod --[[Low]] rbow.b = 0  --[[Next]]
        elseif status==1 then
            if mod<20 then status = 2 end

            rbow.r = mod  --[[Low]] rbow.g = 0 --[[Next]] rbow.b = 255-mod --[[High]]
        elseif status==2 then
            if mod>240 then status = 3 end

            rbow.r = 0 --[[Next]] rbow.g = mod --[[High]] rbow.b = 255-mod --[[Low]]
        elseif status==3 then
            if mod<20 then status = 1 inv=not inv end

            rbow.r = 255-mod --[[High]] rbow.g = mod --[[Low]] rbow.b = 0 --[[Next]]
        end
    end)
end

for i=1,#HatsChat.ChatCol do
    local tbl = HatsChat.ChatCol[i]
    if type(tbl)=="table" and not (tbl.r and tbl.g and tbl.b) then
        local str, col
        for k,v in pairs(tbl) do
            if type(v)=="string" then
                str = v
            elseif type(v)=="table" and (v.r and v.g and v.b) then
                col = v
            end
        end
        if str and col then
            HatsChat.ChatCol[ str ] = col
            print( "HatsChat.ChatCol badly formatted! Line reformatted to:\t\t[\""..str.."\"] = Color( "..tostring(col.r)..", "..tostring(col.g)..", "..tostring(col.b).."),")
        end
    end
    HatsChat.ChatCol[i] = nil
end
if CLIENT then
    HatsChat.Fonts = {}
    function HatsChat.FormatFont( v, ovr )
        ovr = ovr or {}

        local size = GetConVar("hatschat_text_size")
        size = ovr.size or (size and size:GetInt()) or 15
        local font = surface.CreateFont( v.name or v.font, {
            font = v.font,
            size = math.Clamp(v.size or size,10,100), --Font size overrides settings size
            weight = v.weight or 600,
            blursize = v.blursize or 0,
            scanlines = v.scanlines or 0,
            antialias = v.antialias or true,
            underline = v.underline or false,
            italic = v.italic or false,
            strikeout = v.strikeout or false,
            symbol = v.symbol or false,
            rotary = v.rotary or false,
            shadow = v.shadow or false,
            additive = v.additive or false,
            outline = v.outline or false
        })
        HatsChat.Fonts[ v.name or v.font ] = {ManualShadow = v.ManualShadow}
    end

    for _,v in pairs( HatsChat.FontData ) do HatsChat.FormatFont( v ) end --Format fonts
    for _,v in pairs( HatsChat.Emote ) do v.text = string.lower( v.text ) end --Format emotes
    for k,v in pairs( HatsChat.ChatCol ) do --Format colours
        local str = string.lower( k )
        if str~=k then
            HatsChat.ChatCol[k] = nil
            HatsChat.ChatCol[str] = v
        end
        v.ColorPersists = true
    end
    hook.Add( "InitPostEntity", "HatsChat2 TextSize Init", function() --Re-size and refresh fonts
        for _,v in pairs( HatsChat.FontData ) do HatsChat.FormatFont( v ) HatsChat:RefreshLines() end
    end)
else
    for _,v in pairs( HatsChat.FontData ) do if v.filename then resource.AddFile( v.filename ) end end --Add font files
    for _,v in pairs( HatsChat.Emote ) do if v.icon then resource.AddFile( v.icon ) end end --Add emote materials
    for _,v in pairs( HatsChat.LineIcon ) do if v then
        if type(v)=="table" then
            for i=1,#v do resource.AddFile(v[i]) end
        else resource.AddFile( v ) end
    end end --Add icon materials
end

if SERVER then
    AddCSLuaFile()
    AddCSLuaFile( "hatschat/cl_init.lua" )
    AddCSLuaFile( "hatschat/cl_options.lua" )
    AddCSLuaFile( "hatschat/cl_serverbar.lua" )
    AddCSLuaFile( "hatschat/cl_filter.lua" )

    AddCSLuaFile( "hatschat/sh_themes.lua" )
    AddCSLuaFile( "hatschat/cl_chattags.lua" )

    include( "hatschat/sh_themes.lua" )
elseif CLIENT then
    include( "hatschat/cl_init.lua" )
    include( "hatschat/cl_options.lua" )
    include( "hatschat/cl_serverbar.lua" )

    include( "hatschat/cl_chattags.lua" )
    include( "hatschat/cl_filter.lua" )
    --Client-side sh_themes.lua is included at the bottom of cl_init.lua (autorefresh fix)
end
```

but they can still do all the colors, including [rainbow] and [gold], etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still haven't the answer, change your color table to this:

```
HatsChat.ChatCol = {
    ["[red]"] = {r=255,g=0,b=0,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["[green]"] = {r=0,g=255,b=0,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["[blue]"] = {r=0,g=0,b=255,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["[black]"] = {r=0,g=0,b=0,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["[white]"] = {r=255,g=255,b=255,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},

    ["[pink]"] = {r=255,g=0,b=255,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["[teal]"] = {r=0,g=255,b=255,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["[yellow]"] = {r=255,g=255,b=0,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},

    --Minecraft colours
    ["%0"] = {r=0,g=0,b=0,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},       ["Â§0"] = {r=0,g=0,b=0,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly}, --Random escape character, the string is actually §0
    ["%1"] = {r=0,g=0,b=170,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},     ["Â§1"] = {r=0,g=0,b=170,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["%2"] = {r=0,g=170,b=0,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},     ["Â§2"] = {r=0,g=170,b=0,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["%3"] = {r=0,g=170,b=170,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},   ["Â§3"] = {r=0,g=170,b=170,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["%4"] = {r=170,g=0,b=0,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},     ["Â§4"] = {r=170,g=0,b=0,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["%5"] = {r=170,g=0,b=170,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},   ["Â§5"] = {r=170,g=0,b=170,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["%6"] = {r=255,g=170,b=0,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},   ["Â§6"] = {r=255,g=170,b=0,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["%7"] = {r=170,g=170,b=170,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly}, ["Â§7"] = {r=170,g=170,b=170,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["%8"] = {r=85,g=85,b=85,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},    ["Â§8"] = {r=85,g=85,b=85,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["%9"] = {r=85,g=85,b=255,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},   ["Â§9"] = {r=85,g=85,b=255,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["%a"] = {r=85,g=255,b=85,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},   ["Â§a"] = {r=85,g=255,b=85,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["%b"] = {r=85,g=255,b=255,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},  ["Â§b"] = {r=85,g=255,b=255,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["%c"] = {r=255,g=85,b=85,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},   ["Â§c"] = {r=255,g=85,b=85,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["%d"] = {r=255,g=85,b=255,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},  ["Â§d"] = {r=255,g=85,b=255,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["%e"] = {r=255,g=255,b=85,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},  ["Â§e"] = {r=255,g=255,b=85,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},
    ["%f"] = {r=255,g=255,b=255,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly}, ["Â§f"] = {r=255,g=255,b=255,a=255, restricted=DonatorOnly},

    ["[gray]"] = {r=150,g=150,b=150,a=255, restriction=AdminOnly}, --Restrictions are written out completely differently from normal

    ["[gold]"] = {r=255,g=210,b=50,a=255, restriction=AdminOnly, Glow=true}, --Example for glows
    ["[rainbow]"] = {r=255,g=0,b=0,a=255, restriction=AdminOnly}, --Just for fun
    ["[rainbow2]"] = {r=255,g=0,b=0,a=255, restriction=AdminOnly}, --Using WTE's method
}
```

After you added the above colors, remove all the `["none"] = true,` in your local DonatorRank array.
What this will do is, it will allow every rank in the DonatorRank table to access to the chatcolors.